# What is the difference between using of width="200"; and width="200px"?

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between using of width="200" and "width:200px;"?  is both are producing same output in browser?

Comment: `width="200"` is official syntax for images, while `width="200px"` is undefined and incorrect syntax for images.

Comment: one form uses CSS the other form uses HTML. Different interpretations of the same core value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're talking about CSS (`style` attribute) then, if you leave out the unit the browser assumes the default one, which is pixels. That means that it produces the same output from the user's perspective, although that is only because the browser corrects your mistake. Units should always be specified, unless it's value is 0.

For more information see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

If you're talking about the `width` attribute of the element (HTML), then it's used without the unit, because it is always specified by pixels.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp